# Artema Hybrid communication with c++ on Linux

Tags: c++, qt4, serial-port

I am currently trying to integrate a POS system with an Artema Hybrid CC handheld. I am wondering if anyone else has worked on this or something similar.

I can read from the device, that is I receive the ENQ, and send back an ACK in a thread, and I keep it open for reading/writing, but everything I try to write from it simply does nothing.

Here is the code for the function to write the data:

```
void PayLife::sendPayLifeData(QString data) {

  int len = data.length();
  int i = 0;
  char lrc = 0;
  char stx = 0x02;
  char etx = 0x03;
  char ack = 0x06;
  char * bytes;
  int ret;
  char buffer[132];

  bytes = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 10);
  strcpy(bytes,data.toLatin1().data());
  qDebug() << "PayLife Sending data: " << data << " of len " << QString::number(len) <<
          " " << " Bytes is: " << bytes ;
  while (i < len) {
    lrc ^= bytes[i];
    i++;
  }
  /* sprintf(buffer,"%c%c%s%c%c",ack,stx,bytes,etx,lrc);
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
    printf("c: %X ", buffer[i]);
  }
  printf(" [[ %s ]] \n", buffer); */
  qDebug() << "Starting";
  write(this->descriptor,&ack,1);
  usleep(100000);
  write(this->descriptor,&stx,1);
  usleep(100000);
  ret = write(this->descriptor,bytes,132);
  usleep(100000);
  write(this->descriptor,&etx,1);
  usleep(100000);
  write(this->descriptor,&lrc,1);
  qDebug() << "Done";
  free(bytes);
}
```

The data argument is: E11U000008507000099VZ000000

Of course, the documentation is in German, which I don't speak, so this is as far as I have gotten. I've basically got 1 month to implement this then I have to give the device back.

If anyone has any pointers, or some example code that would be awesome.

/jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transport protocol looks like something standard, so maybe you should only send `len` bytes of the data not 132 and include the ETX character in the `lrc` summing ?

It might be easier and clearer to use `QByteArray` instead of `malloc` arrays or `QString` (`QString` are for user displayed strings which is not the case here):

```
void PayLife::sendPayLifeData(const QByteArray & data) {
    static const char stx = 0x02;
    static const char etx = 0x03;
    static const char ack = 0x06;

    QByteArray buffer = stx + data + etx;
    // Calculate the xor sum on data + etx
    char lrc = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < buffer.size(); ++i) {
       lrc ^= buffer[i];
    }
    buffer += lrc;

    qDebug() << "Starting";
    write(this->descriptor, &ack, 1);
    write(this->descriptor, buffer.data(), buffer.size()); 
    qDebug() << "Done";       
}
```

You should also have a look at `QSerialDevice`, it could allow you to implement the protocol in a more event driven way with signal and slots.

Comment: This is more or less essentially what I came up with as well. And yes, as it turned out ETX must be in the LRC, so I am happy to say it is currently working in Linux, but I am not trying to get it to work on Windows, so this QSerialPort may be the answer, so thanks!